# Getting boxes and text to appear in the correct way

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dashboard and I'm having a bit of an issue with my lay out

I am able to get 4 boxes together with some text but I cant get the text in the correct place and I need to add another box in the middle and I'm unsure how to do so

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#first,
#second,
#third,
#fourth {
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h2 align="center">PI Graphs</h2>
<div style="width: 250px; height: 240px; margin-left: 10px">
  <div id="first" style="float: left; border-top-left-radius:10px;">
    <p>Locations Counted</p>
  </div>
  <div id="second" style="float: left; border-top-right-radius:10px;">
    <p>Locations Accurate</p>
  </div>
  <div id="third" style="float: left; border-bottom-left-radius:10px;">
    <p>Serial Not Exist</p>
  </div>
  <div id="fourth" style="float: left; border-bottom-right-radius:10px;">
    <p>Serials Wrong Location</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: currently]

this is what I end up with and this is what I need it to resemble

[image]

can somebody give me some help on how to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, for this kind of design, you would probably be best to go for an HTML markup that splits a container into multiple rows, but alternatively, you can take advantage of flexbox as in the following suggested solution.

Since we're trying to retain the markup you're using, in order to create the centered box in your image, we will have to take it out of the flow and then center it using:

- `position: absolute`,
- `top: 50%`,
- `left: 50%` and
- `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`.

**Snippet:**

```css
.container {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.box {
  color: #fff;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #70ad47;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.box.top-row {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.box.bottom-row {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.box > p {
  text-align: center;
}

#tl-box {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
 
#tr-box {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#bl-box {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#br-box {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

#cc-box {
  color: #0c0e0c;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #bbd3b1;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h2 align = "center">PI Graphs</h2>
<div class = "container">
  <div id = "tl-box" class = "box top-row">
    <p>Locations Counted</p>
  </div>
  <div id = "tr-box" class = "box top-row">
    <p>Locations Accurate</p>
  </div>
  <div id = "bl-box" class = "box bottom-row">
    <p>Serial Not Exist</p>
  </div>
  <div id = "br-box" class = "box bottom-row">
    <p>Serials Wrong Location</p>
  </div>
  <div id = "cc-box" class = "box">
    <p>Current Days Accuracy 98%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this looks exactly like what i want but when i run it on mine the dark green boxes all run down in a line any suggestion

Comment: Hey @Jamie, can you elaborate on what the outcome you see is? Is there any code you use that might interfere?

Comment: @AngelPolitis all of my dark green boxes are in a single file line down the middle

Comment: Yes, that can happen when using flexbox, if the container is wide enough for all of them to fit. Make sure to restrict its width to a fixed value (like in the example) or use `width: 50%` to the `.box` elements, so that they scale appropriately, while only two fit in each row.

Comment: @AngelPolitis great yea that fixed it thank you very much